# How to modify <head> elements programmatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

Is there a way to programmatically access and modify the `<head>` section of the page in ASP.NET MVC? I need to update the page's `<meta>` tags depending on which data the user is viewing on any given page.

Comment: Use a combination of Darin's and Jakub's suggestion to get the best result ie. create the contentplaceholder on your master page and use a BaseViewModel approach. the result `<asp:Content ID="IndexMetas" ContentPlaceHolderID="Metas" runat="server">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<%: Model.Meta %>" />
</asp:Content>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a content placeholder in the master page which you override in each view:

```
<head>
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Metas" runat="server" />
...
```

and in the view:

```
<asp:Content ID="IndexMetas" ContentPlaceHolderID="Metas" runat="server">
    <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords specific to the view" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<meta name="description" content="<%: Model.Meta %>" />
```

Comment: Just to note, using the second approach you will probably need to create a BaseViewModel to use this more effectively.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers returns actually a collection of the response http headers. It has nothing to do with the <head> html element.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET 4.0 there are several new properties of the Page which you can use to set meta-tags directly like this:

```
Page.MetaKeywords = "asp.net,c#"; 
Page.MetaDescription = "This is my stackoverflow post";
```

You can read more about them here http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2010/03/23/asp-net-4-0-meta-tags-and-search-engine-optimisation.aspx